# Implementing Azure AD b2c in xamarin does not keep track of logged in user

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-ad-b2c

In an iOS app, On login button click I have this code.

```cs
AuthenticationResult ar =
    await App.PCA.AcquireTokenAsync(App.Scopes,
        GetUserByPolicy(App.PCA.Users, App.PolicySignUpSignIn), App.UiParent);
```

This takes me to B2C web page and after successful login, it comes back to the app.

`OnResume()` I have the following code

```cs
AuthenticationResult ar =
    await App.PCA.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(App.Scopes,
        GetUserByPolicy(App.PCA.Users, App.PolicySignUpSignIn), App.Authority, false);
```

Which throws an exception because `App.PCA.Users.Count` is 0.

Why doesn't it keep track of the user that was just logged in?

Note: I am testing on the simulator.